# How to change path segment joint geometry in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I'm using `path = paper.Path(point1, point2)` and `path.add(pointN)` to create a polyline:

[image]

I want the joints made with circles, like the following:

[image]

How can I make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`path.strokeJoin`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokejoin) to  'miter', 'round' or 'bevel' (default is 'miter'), and [`path.strokeCap`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokecap) to 'round', 'square' or 'butt' (default is 'butt').

Comment: Exact output can be achieved by setting [path.strokeJoin](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokejoin) additionally.